# Get content of element and output percentage of value into sibling element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which contains a series of products with prices. Next to these prices in a sibling element I need to output a percentage value of the original price along with some explanatory offer text.

The elements don't have IDs just to add that in as a complication.

An example of the code I have is as follows...

```
<div class="info">
    <div class="figure">£<span>300.00</span></div>
    <div class="offer"><!--percentage goes here--></div>
</div>

<div class="info">
    <div class="figure">£<span>450.00</span></div>
    <div class="offer"><!--percentage goes here--></div>
</div>
```

and so far my jquery looks like this...

```
var str = $( ".figure span" ).text();
$(".offer").html( str/100*5 ).prepend ("£").append( " spread over xx months" );
```

This correctly returns £22.5 spread over xx months in the 'offer' div.

This is great if I'm just using it once on the page, but it will repeat down the page with differing figures and when I do that the percentage will not output. So my question is how do I get this to work on repeating elements.

I also need to get the resulting figure to two decimal places. I know I should use .toFixed(2) but I'm not quite sure how that should be applied here.

Comment: what's the span for in _$( ".figure span" )_

Comment: The span was my way of dealing with the £ symbol, but I see from your answer below that there's a better way o deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/4wXN7/2/

For each *info figure*, get its value and apply it to the next sibling which is *offer*

```
$('.info .figure').each(function(){
    var str = $(this).text().replace('£','');
    $(this).next().html( (str/100*5).toFixed(2) ).prepend ("£").append( " spread over xx months" );
});
```

Comment: That's it. It seems pretty obvious now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly, you want to set every div with the class "offer".
You can do this as follows:

```
$('.offer').each(function() {
    // do your stuff here
    $(this).text('Put your value here');
});
```

This code loops through all divs with the class "offer".
I hope this helps you.